# How include Jquery widget datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a problem when I would like include a datepicker widget.
I would like do like here : [enter link description here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range).
I download the zip but here : [enter link description here](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.10.4&themeParams=none&components=1000000000001000000000000000000000)

Here my html code :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#from").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
        $("#to").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from"/>
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to"/>
   </div> 
<br />
<table id="table_campaigns" class="display">
    <caption style="font-size:20px">Statistiek 6</caption>
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<br />
<br />

<table id="table1" class="display">
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have this : SyntaxError: syntax error

Did I download the right zip? What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min"></script>
```

Dont use both, just one of them...

And also you have wrong file name, you are missing `.js`

Comment: thank you. Datepicker works well but I have an error with my datatable TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function
"bAutoWidth": false. Why?

Answer (score 1):

From http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/datepicker/

```
Additional Notes:

This widget requires some functional CSS, otherwise it won't work. 
If you build a custom theme, use the widget's specific CSS file as a starting point.
```

You should include jquery-ui.css

Comment: Thank you too but I have an error with my datatable TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function "bAutoWidth": false. Why?

Comment: I don't see any `<script src="js/datatable.js"></script>`, did you load it (with it's .css) ?

Comment: I have a html page that is the index and it includes the js and css file.

Comment: When I remove the datepicker, I have no problem. But when I add the datepicker the datepicker at the top of my datatable, I have the error

Comment: Better open a new question, it has nothing to do with this question anymore ;) By the way, datatables needs jQuery.js (not UI, but jQuery itself), did you include it BEFORE including datatables.js ? Or you can edit your question if it is not that different from the current one.

Comment: Ok I found, I include in 2 differents html pages. Thank you.